# How to change an element in an array in python after a conditional check

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Hey Guys Im a Python Beginner and as a learning project I am making a tic tac toe game with the pygame module. (RED and GREEN instead of "X" and "O") I have this problem: I want to check who won so I made an array with a field like this

```
all = [["00", "01", "02"],
      ["10", "11", "12"],
      ["20", "21", "22"]]
```

It contains all possible locations in the tictactoe grid and when a player clicks on a grid with the mouse I check where he clicked and give that info into a loop which should change the value in the grid to a simple Marker so I know if it was RED or GREEN who clicked there.

Example loop for RED:

```
  for r in all:
            for c in r:
                if c == str(row) + str(column):


                    c = "R"
```

The last part won't work. It does not assign the value to the array and if I print the array it is unchanged. It only assigns it to the variable c, but I want this. (Example, I click grid part 01 ad RED):

```
all = [["00", "R", "02"],
      ["10", "11", "12"],
      ["20", "21", "22"]]
```

Thanks in advance. I know it might be a dumb question but Im stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
c = "R"
```

you're not *overwriting* the value in `c` - you're *replacing* it. In other words, you're making `c` point to a completely different data source, when it was originally pointing to somewhere in the list. The original data source - the list - remains unchanged.

Simplest way to address the problem is to loop with *indices* instead:

```
for r in range(len(all)):
    for c in range(len(all[r])):
        if all[r][c] == str(row) + str(column):
            all[r][c] = "R"
```

This way, when you do

```
all[r][c] = "R"
```

you're changing the value in the list, permanently.

Comment: Hey thank you for the fast answer, but I am still getting this error here:  for r in range(all):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: in range you need to take size of your list so use len method `len (all)` ;)

Comment: Wow thank you so much!! Works like a charm now :)))

Answer (score 0):

The variable c is only your position.

If you want stick with your code, just use your `row` and `column` indexes to set correct place in array `all`

```
for r in all:
    for c in r:
        if c == str(row) + str(column):
            all[row][column] = "R"
```

Edit: using `for x in range()` ;)

```
for r in range(len(all)):
    for c in range(len(all[r])):
        if all[r][c] == str(row) + str(column):
            all[r][c] = "R"
```

Comment: thanks, but I think I didnt show enough, the row and column are from somewhere else, they are just the numbers I get from the mouse click event. I want to compare them to an element in the array and then change it if it exists

Comment: @odod take a look or maybe edit your description to explain your problem more precisely ;)

Comment: yeah you are right, its my first post and Im not really that good at explaining, sorry :s